# Change color of p tag on hover of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs aligned next to eachother in a parent div. The first div contains an image, the second div contains text in a p tag. On hovering either the img or the p tag, the content must be affected: the img src must be altered AND the color of the p tag must be altered.

It looks like this:

```
[DIVLEFT - IMG][DIVRIGHT - text here]
[DIVLEFT - IMG][DIVRIGHT - text here]
[DIVLEFT - IMG][DIVRIGHT - text here]
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="row1">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <img src="photo.png" onmouseover="this.src='photo_hover.png';"
        onmouseout="this.src='photo.png';">
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn"><p id="text1">text here</p></div>
</div>

<div id="row2">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <img src="photo.png" onmouseover="this.src='photo_hover.png';"
        onmouseout="this.src='photo.png';">
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn"><p id="text2">text here</p></div>
</div>

<div id="row3">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <img src="photo.png" onmouseover="this.src='photo_hover.png';"
        onmouseout="this.src='photo.png';">
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn"><p id="text2">text here</p></div>
</div>
```

Some CSS:

```
.rightcolumn {
  text-align:left;
  color:#838383;
}
```

At this point, the image is changed on hover, but the text in the p tag is not. I think the best solution is to have a JS function that changes the img and the color of the p tag. This function is then called when hovering over either the img or the p tag. However, I'm unable to produce such a function.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How it must be altered ?

Comment: You need to use Javascript to do it. Search for ``hover`` event, and then just change ``style.color`` on `p` element and ``src`` on ``img`` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `class="row"` where you have `id="row1"` etc.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ghykdrpx/1/

Then use the following jQuery:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(".row").hover(function () {
    jQuery('p', this).addClass("changeColor");
    jQuery('img', this).attr("src", "photo_hover.png");
  }, function () {
    jQuery('p', this).removeClass("changeColor");
    jQuery('img', this).attr("src", "photo.png");
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.rightcolumn {
  text-align:left;
  color:#838383;
}

.changeColor {
  color:red !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="row1">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <img src="photo.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn"><p id="text1">text here</p></div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="row2">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <img src="photo.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn"><p id="text2">text here</p></div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="row3">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <img src="photo.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn"><p id="text2">text here</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use jQuery's function [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Add a class to identify your element that has the two tags nested and add `data` attributes to your `img`.

Now use this piece of code and it works just fine.

HTML

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" data-src="http://placehold.it/350x150/" data-src-hover="http://placehold.it/350x150/E8117F/ffffff">
<p data-color="black" data-color-hover="magenta">text here</p>
```

JS

```
$( ".hover-element" ).hover(
  function() {
    var jThis = $(this);
    var image = jThis.find("img");
    var p = jThis.find("p");
    image.attr("src", image.data("hover-src"));
    p.css("color",p.data("hover-color"));
  }, function() {
    var jThis = $(this);
    var image = jThis.find("img");
    var p = jThis.find("p");
    image.attr("src",image.data("src"));
    p.css("color",p.data("color"));
  }
);
```

Working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/3ej4pxpy/13)

Comment: This method would require the OP to apply separate functions to each row individually

Comment: .. I am _so_ sorry to assume OP would change **constants** i added to **show example functionality** of this snippet. Yeah add a `data` attr and read it, that was not a requierment and is a no brainer. No reason to downvote a working code snippet that just does not have further functionality.

Comment: That is indeed a better approach. You should update your answer to incorporate that logic.

Comment: You could also improve your improvement by caching `$(this)` ; )

Comment: I know it is, i just did not include it because the snippet was soley to show the functionality of `hover()`, just as the OP asked for and wanted to add a quick answer.

Comment: Now it's _utter prefection_! Haha! I'm also a little sad i'm the only one that got a downvote for using fixed values :'(

Comment: I figured it was a losing battle when 5 others poped up suggesting the same   ; )

Comment: The typo.. i am dishonored, my perfection is gone. And well, it is indeed useless in a complete solution, but i think it was pretty obvious it has to be changed, just like the `data` attributes with the images in it.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't resist

Comment: To be fair, while the use of data attributes is obvious to some, it might not have been to someone who was unaware of `hover()` and its use. You should be heralded for your good deeds and fine tutelage of this OP

Comment: You have a point there, yes he probably does not know. Too bad OP probably will never see this as he already accepted a answer pretty much as useful as my inital one. PS: _Magnificent_ choice of words!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the javascript to the div's that contain them:

```js
$(".container-row").hover(function(){
         var $this = $(this);
         var $img = $(this).find("img").first();
         $img.attr("src", $img.data("hover"));
         // else to modify the related div on mouseenter
         $this.find("p").first().css("color","red");
    },function(){
         var $this = $(this);
         var $img = $(this).find("img").first();
         $img.attr("src", $img.data("original"));
         // else to modify the related div on mouseleave
         $this.find("p").first().css("color","black");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="row1" class="container-row">
        <div class="leftcolumn">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" data-hover="http://placehold.it/350x150/000000/ffffff" data-original="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        </div>
        <div class="rightcolumn"><p id="text1">text here</p></div>
    </div>

    <div id="row2" class="container-row">
        <div class="leftcolumn">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" data-hover="http://placehold.it/350x150/000000/ffffff" data-original="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        </div>
        <div class="rightcolumn"><p id="text2">text here</p></div>
    </div>    

    <div id="row3" class="container-row">
        <div class="leftcolumn">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" data-hover="http://placehold.it/350x150/000000/ffffff" data-original="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        </div>
        <div class="rightcolumn"><p id="text3">text here</p></div>
    </div>
```

**Note**: By referencing `$(this)` to `$this`, I intended to prevent running unnecessary jQuery methods to call `$()` every time I need to access `this` as a `jQuery Object`. That's a common practice.

Answer (score 0):

I would set it up using classes with mouseenter and mouseleave and utilize data attributes to store the hover values like so:

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave','.lft-img, .text', function(){
  var $this=$(this);
    var $row=$this.closest('.row');
    var $text=$row.find('.text');
    var $img=$row.find('.lft-img');
    
    var color=$text.css('backgroundColor');
    var otherColor=$text.data('other-color');
    
    var otherImg=$img.data('other-img');
    var img=$img.attr('src');
    
    $text.data('other-color',color).css('backgroundColor',otherColor)
    $img.data('other-img',img).attr('src',otherImg);
    
    
});
```

```css
.rightcolumn {
  text-align: left;
  color: #838383;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <img class="lft-img" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" data-other-img="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Other image&w=350&h=150">
  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumn">
    <p class="text" data-other-color="red">text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <img class="lft-img" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" data-other-img="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Other image&w=350&h=150">
  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumn">
    <p class="text" data-other-color="blue">text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <img class="lft-img" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" data-other-img="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Other image&w=350&h=150">
  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumn">
    <p class="text" data-other-color="#cccccc">text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this no need of using javascript or jquery

```
 <div id="row1">
 <div class="leftcolumn">
    <img src="photo.png" onmouseover="this.src='photo_hover.png';"
    onmouseout="this.src='photo.png';">
 </div>
 <div class="rightcolumn"><p id="text1" onmouseover="this.innerHTML='hello';" onmouseout="this.innerHTML='bye bye';">text here</p></div>
 </div>

 <div id="row2">
 <div class="leftcolumn">
    <img src="photo.png" onmouseover="this.src='photo_hover.png'; "
    onmouseout="this.src='photo.png';">
 </div>
 <div class="rightcolumn"><p id="text2" onmouseover="this.innerHTML='hello';" onmouseout="this.innerHTML='bye bye';">text here</p></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rightcolumn {
  text-align:left;
  color:#838383;
 }

#text1:hover,#text2:hover{
  color:red;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using simple javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<script>
function change1(x) {
    x.src = "photo_hover.png";
    var y=document.getElementById("text1");
    y.style.color="red";
}

function change2(x) {
      x.src = "photo.png";
    var y=document.getElementById("text1");
    y.style.color="blue";
}
</script>
<body>

<div id="row1">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <img src="photo.png" onmouseover="change1(this)"
        onmouseout="change2(this)">
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn"><p id="text1">text here</p></div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also without changing your html.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $("[id^=row]").mouseenter( function() {
                // for the image hover
                 $('img', $(this)).attr('src', 'photo_hover.png');
                // for the text hover
                  $('p', $(this)).css('color', 'red');

            }).mouseleave(function() {
                // for the image hover out
                $('img', $(this)).attr('src','photo.png');
                // for the text hover out
                $('p', $(this)).css('color', 'black');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Or instead

```
<style>
    [id^="row"]:hover p {
      color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<div id="row1" class="row">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <img src="photo.png" >
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn"><p id="text1">text here</p></div>
</div>

<div id="row2" class="row">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <img src="photo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn"><p id="text2">text here</p></div>
</div>

<div id="row3" class="row">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <img src="photo.png" >
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn"><p id="text2">text here</p></div>
</div>
```

Just remove the mouseover and mouseout event from image and use this jquery code snippet if you what content change on any row ie on either img or p tag

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.row').on('mouseover', function() {
                $(this).find('img').src('photo_hover.png');
                $(this).find('p').css('color', '#ff0000');
            });
            $('.row').on('mouseout', function() {
                $(this).find('img').src('photo.png');
                $(this).find('p').css('color', '#000');
            });
        });
    </script>
```